# Passing Cell as a range object in VBA and then assigning the value

Tags: excel, vba, range, variable-assignment

I am trying to pass merged cell "G8" (consists of G8:G11) as an argument to the function as range object:

```
@XYZ(O8,P8,E8,S8,G8)
```

[image]

```vb
Function XYZ (varA As String, varB As Integer, varC As String, varD As String, **varE As Range**)

    If varD = "User Defined" Then

        VarE.Value = "White" or some other string value from worksheet
    
    End If

End Function
```

I can get the address of the cell with:

```
varE.Address = $G$8
```

I did try different variations but I am unable to assign the string value or any value to this cell.

Comment: UDFs work like Excel's built-in functions in that they can only modify the display of the cell in which they reside. If you want to modify the display of G8 the function, user-defined or otherwise, must be designed to reside in G8.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a user defined function to alter a worksheet, and that includes setting the value of a cell.

Comment: Thanks for responding Norie. Then what is the correct way to alter the cell value based off the condition from another cell value?

Comment: You could create code that does it and then run that code, but you can't do it with a user defined function or a formula. Is there something specific you are trying to achieve?